# Can the Mac OS X Server Contacts feature hold my customers contacts informations?

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, contacts

Mounting a Mac Os X domain for a very active but small-in-size company. We would like to centralize our clients/customers'contacts as a kind of database.
That is what we thought we could do with the feature but the clarity of the documentation and the multitude of help for that is unsatisfactory.
Hope you guys can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that all of your users have accounts on the server. Make sure you have Open Directory turned on.

What you want to do IS indeed possible. There are two ways to accomplish this (assuming that you're using Mountain Lion Server).

1)You will need to create a user called, say, Business Contacts, and add that Contacts account to each of your users' computers. Users will be able to edit, add, and remove contacts if you go this way.

2) Add each contact to Open Directory and then add the directory contacts to the Contacts server (this is what the checkbox on the Contacts server pane is for). The upside of this is that your users can't mess around with the stored contacts. The downside is that you will have to add all of the contacts yourself if any need to be added/changed in the future.

For a small company, the first solution is probably the most practical (along with regular backups).

Comment: _all of your users have accounts on the server_ check.
_Mountain Lion Server_ on _Open Directory turned on_ check.

_create a user called, say, Business Contacts_ ok, but
_add that Contacts account to each of your users' computers_ I am not sure what you mean by that; since the end user has an account on the serveur, he would be login in as that user account and therefore will be using Contacts.app as that domain user.

so how do I _add that Contacts account to each of_ my _users' computers_ ?

please excuse my non native english (although Apple's naming convention isn't helping here).

Comment: The Contacts.app will need to have two user accounts on each machine: the domain user (i.e. the user that is logged in to the computer) and the "Business Contacts" user. Go to Contacts.app -> Preferences -> Accounts. Select CardDAV. Enter the short name and password of the contacts user. The server address is your server.

Comment: I see!
Back to work next week where I'll be testing and probably creating a "tutorial" as well as replying with a smile ;)

Merci Beaucoup !

Comment: Did this end up working for you?

Comment: Doing it right now.
A question arose though, let say i have the contact all setup

Comment: operation has been reported, new priorities arose.
Will let you know sometimes next week.